# Create MPI processes on the fly with fork?

Tags: fork, mpi, inter-process-communicat

If I use MPI, I have a number of processes specified when I run the main program. However I would like to start with one process and dynamically decide at runtime if and when I need more, to fork more processes off. Is that or something similar possible?

Otherwise I would have to reinvent MPI which I would very much like to avoid.

Comment: I refer you to my answer to [this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683331/changing-number-of-processors-during-execution-of-the-code-in-mpis-based-paralle/9683758#9683758

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: But that just starts a new process. This is not exactly a copy on write `fork` from the precise location (and configuration) of the current process.

Comment: you asked 'is that or something similar possible ?', I propose that mph_comm_spawn is similar.  But if it isn't suitable for your requirements you may be left with having to rewrite MPI. Or use another parallelisation library / toolset / approach.

Comment: Since you are speaking of forking, it looks like all your processes are running on the same node. MPI doesn't make this kind of assumption, and MPI processes might be scattered among many nodes on a cluster. This is why, as HighPerformanceMark says, the closest MPI operation to what you desire is a spawn. To do a kind of fork the MPI way, you'd have to spawn a new process and send it its initial state using P2P communications.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to use `fork()` as the child process will not be able to use MPI functions. There is a simple mechanism in MPI to create dynamically new processes. You must use the `MPI_Comm_spawn` function or the `MPI_Comm_spawn_mutliple`

OpenMPI doc: http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn.3.php

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_SPAWNS 2

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  int np = NUM_SPAWNS;
  int errcodes[NUM_SPAWNS];
  MPI_Comm parentcomm, intercomm;

  MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
  MPI_Comm_get_parent( &parentcomm );
  if (parentcomm == MPI_COMM_NULL) {
    MPI_Comm_spawn( "spawn_example", MPI_ARGV_NULL, np, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, errcodes );
    printf("I'm the parent.\n");
  } else {
    printf("I'm the spawned.\n");
  }
  fflush(stdout);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```